# how to get a char variable in a structure to take on the value of a char pointer

Tags: c

I'm working on one of my CS assignments parsing a .csv file and I'm confused on how to get a normal char variable inside of my structure to equal the value of a char pointer array index that holds a single character.

This is my .h file
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETpG2.jpg

This is my .c file
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuZcG.jpg

As you can see I'm attempting to get airData[j]->controlTower = tokens[14].  I have fixed this issue to run correctly by making the controlTower variable into a pointer inside of the structure, but because of assignment rules I'm not allowed to do this.

Currently, the compiler is throwing a " incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char **'; dereference with * " warning. Also, when ran it prints out random characters airData[i]->controlTower. I'm not sure to interpret this issue, which seems to be the cause of the bug.

Comment: The second link is broken.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the entire error message so that it is accurate? I think you mistyped `char **` instead of just `char *`.

Comment: Post code, not pictures.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`tokens[14]` is a `char *`, so you need to dereference it to get the underlying `char`. I.e.

```
airData[j]->controlTower = *tokens[14]
```

Comment: I fixed the image so you can view the rest of my code, but I actually solved the issue by dereferencing it with airData[j]->controlTower = *tokens[14] because of your suggestion. Appreciate it!

Comment: @Jeremy Then please mark it as an answer by clicking the check mark on the left.